# I want sum of time divide by sum of people of the top two weights in one formula

Tags: excel

[image: Excel Sheet Raw Data]

I want sum of time divide by sum of people of the top two weights in one formula. The result should give me 0.7857142857.

e.g. 
The formula should pick up the biggest two weights (30% and 40% of Row A). And then take (C4+C7)/(B4+B7)

Is there a way to express this in one formula?

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head:

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,">="&LARGE(A2:A7,2))/SUMIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,">="&LARGE(A2:A7,2))
```

[image]